# Depends On Groups Method is not executing prorperly from another class file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

There are two separate class files.
Inside `Vehicle.java` file there are 2 groups `Bike & Car` and each group is having 3 different methods.

Refer below code snippets.

```
public class Vehicle {

    @Test (groups = {"Car"})
    public void car1()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Car 1 Method.");
    }

    @Test (groups = {"Bike"})
    public void bike1()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Bike 1 Method.");
    }

    @Test (groups = {"Car"})
    public void car2()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Car 2 Method.");
    }

    @Test (groups = {"Bike"})
    public void bike2()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Bike 2 Method.");
    }

    @Test (groups = {"Car"})
    public void car3()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Car 3 Method.");
    }

    @Test (groups = {"Bike"})
    public void bike3()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Bike 3 Method.");
    }
}
```

Another class file is `Dependent.java`. Inside this file I have called one group `Bike` from `Vehicle.java` file.

Then I run the `Dependent.java` file. That time `Car` group is also executing along with `Bike` group. 
But in my `Dependent.java` file I have not called `Car` group.

Refer `Dependent.java` file code snippet.

```
public class Dependent {

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"openbrowser"})
    public void login()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Login Method Called..");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = {"Bike"})
    public void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Setup Method Called..");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"setup"})
    public void openbrowser()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : Openbrowser Method Called..");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
    public void logout()
    {
        System.out.println("Message : After login Method Called..");
    }

}
```

Edited Code :-
Here is my testing.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Demo TestNG">
 <test verbose="2" name="Cross Browser">

    <classes>
            <class name="com.abc.Dependent" />      
    </classes>

  </test> 
</suite>
```

Can anybody tell me how to handle this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close and restart your IDE and use following .xml:

```
 <suite name="Suite" verbose="1">
<test name="Test1">

    <groups>
        <run>

        <exclude name="Car" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>

        <class name="example.Dependent" />
        <class name="example.Vehicle" />


    </classes>

</test>


 </suite>
```