# I am getting null pointer exception while running testng code through XML.But when running code directly its working fine

Tags: selenium, automation, testng

Code is Grouping in TESTNG

```
 package testNG_annot;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

    public class TestNG_grp1
     {
      @BeforeMethod
      public void CarBM() {
                System.out.println("CarBM");
            }
        ***  // Created group car and Two wheeler//***
            @Test(groups = { "Car" })
            public void Sedan1() {
                System.out.println("Test1-Verna");
            }

            @Test(groups = { "Car" })
            public void Sedan2() {
                System.out.println("Test2-BMW");
            }

            @Test(groups = { "TwoWheeler" })
            public void Scooter1() {
                System.out.println("Test3-ScootyPep");
            }

            @Test(groups = { "TwoWheeler" })
            public void aScooter2() {
                System.out.println("Test4-TVS");
            }
           }
```

suite.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <suite name="grp11"> 
    <test name="group1"> 
      <gropus> 
        <run> 
          <include name="Car"/> 
        </run> 
      </gropus> 
      <classes> 
        <class name="testNG_annot.TestNG_grp1"/> 
      </classes> 
    </test> 
  </suite>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="grp11">
<test name="group1">
<gropus>
<run>
<include name="Car"/>
</run>
</gropus>
<classes>
<class name="testNG_annot.TestNG_grp1"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>

Comment: change the spelling for groups. It could be the reason for your error.

Comment: refer this question, it will resolved your query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844611/depends-on-groups-method-is-not-executing-prorperly-from-another-class-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spelling for **groups** tag is wrong. Change the spelling and run it again.

```
<groups>
   <run>
      <include name="Car"/>
   </run>
</groups>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form the testng.xml file as below format. Run it as testng test and you will get your test running.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1">
  <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="testNG_annot.TestNG_grp1" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: groups tag is misspelled. so the testng cant fetch that class file. change it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Keep this on top in your xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```